# Searching on class names with a dash ('-')

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, canonical-quickly

I'm messing around with `lxml` in Python, but can't seem to figure out how to use the `cssselect()` function to get all `div`'s with the class `reddit-entry`, as it seems to dislike the `-` character. Any other class name without `-` works fine.

Comment: Umm... not sure about that - does `obj.xpath('//div[@class="reddit-entry"]')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a bug in the parser in lxml.cssselect. I took over maintenance of the project and extracted it from lxml. The bug is fixed in the new cssselect: http://packages.python.org/cssselect/

lxml 2.4 will use the new cssselect, but until then the way to use it is:

```
from cssselect import HTMLTranslator
result = lxml_document.xpath(HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath('div.reddit-entry'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code that cssselector uses via xpath it does work...

```
obj.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' reddit-entry ')]")
```